# Make margin between items scalable and same value depending on device's screen size

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, margin

I have in my application 7 ToggleButton in the **oval** shape (as Weekdays - see AOSP clock application) and I'd love to implement margin between them which will be everywhere the same and ToggleButtons will fill whole view horizontally. To say it more fairly, I'm looking something like `android:layout_weight` but instead of scalling item's width (cause its shape) to scale margin between them.

Code for my ToggleButtons:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/monday"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:textOff="M"
                android:textOn="M"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                />
                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/tuesday"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:textOff="T"
                    android:textOn="T"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/wednesday"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:textOff="W"
                    android:textOn="W"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/thursday"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:textOff="T"
                    android:textOn="T"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/friday"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:textOff="F"
                    android:textOn="F"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/saturday"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                    android:textOff="S"
                    android:textOn="S"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/sunday"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:textOff="S"
                    android:textOn="S"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a `ConstraintLayout` as your parent viewgroup, and then create a `spread_inside` horizontal chain between your views:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#caf"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/two"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#caf"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/one"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/three"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#caf"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/two"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/four"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#caf"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/three"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/five"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/five"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#caf"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/four"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/six"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/six"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#caf"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/five"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/seven"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#caf"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/six"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle` attribute on the first view is key here; it makes the space be distributed evenly only between the views. You can try the other values too to see which you like best.

[image]

[image]

If you don't want to use `ConstraintLayout`, the other way to do it would be to use a `LinearLayout`, but add a `Space` view between each of your main views, and give the `Space` views weight:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#caf"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#caf"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#caf"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#caf"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/five"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#caf"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/six"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#caf"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#caf"/>

</LinearLayout>
```